# java.lang.NullPointerException: null for JDBC

Tags: spring, authentication

I have an User PoJo with UserDao and UserDaoImpl.
My Password hash is based on PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256.
I am use Spring Security Corw 4.2.3 and Spring Authentication Manager
I have created my Authentication Provider.

Here is my User DAOIMPL

```
package com.enlight.yaadle.uplift.user;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

//import javax.swing.tree.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.enlight.yaadle.uplift.security.StrongPassImpl;
import com.enlight.yaadle.uplift.user.User;

@Component
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao,UserDetailsService {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class);

      @Autowired
      JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

      public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {  this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;     }
      public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {  return jdbcTemplate;   }


      public void register(User user) {
            final String CREATE_USER = "INSERT INTO USERS (username, displayname, email, password, id,enabled) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? , ?, ?)";

            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();String id=randomUUIDString;

            try {
                String hashPass = StrongPassImpl.generateHash(user.getPassword());
                int status = jdbcTemplate.update(CREATE_USER,user.getEmail(),user.getUsername(),user.getEmail(),hashPass,id,false);
                //logger.info(hashPass);
                logger.info("User Updated status: "+ status + "\nDisplay UserName: "+ user.getUsername() + "\nDisplay Email: "+ user.getEmail() + 
                        "\nDisplay Password: "+ user.getPassword()+  "\nDisplay Id:" + id   );

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
              catch (InvalidKeySpecException e)  { e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        public User findUserByEmail(User login) {
            logger.info("I am inside findbyemail");
            final String sql = "SELECT EMAIL,PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME='" + login.getUsername() +"'";
            logger.info("Query made " + sql);

            User principal=jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new UserRowMapper());
            logger.info("Query made " + principal.getUsername());

            return principal;

            }

public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User>
 {
    public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    logger.info("I am inside mapper");
    User user = new User();
    user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
    user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
    return user;
}
}

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public User loadUserByUsername(User login) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }


        }
```

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.enlight.yaadle.uplift.user.UserDaoImpl.findUserByEmail(UserDaoImpl.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.enlight.yaadle.uplift.security.YaadleAuthProvider.authenticate(YaadleAuthProvider.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the NPE is thrown in the line

```
logger.info("Query made " + principal.getUsername());
```

Your query returns null (cannot find the user).

According to your comment SQL is

```
SELECT EMAIL,PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME='don@gmail,com'
```

Does the user exists (email contains comma 'don@gmail,com')? I think not.

BTW the code has SQL injection. Define a parameter instead in the SQL

```
SELECT EMAIL,PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME=?
```

and pass the value as a parameter to remove the SQL injection.

Add processing of cases when email is not correct and user with specified login does not exist - e.g. check whether the query returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your logs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.enlight.yaadle.uplift.user.UserDaoImpl.findUserByEmail(UserDaoImpl.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
```

It should be sth is null. Can you check your `User login` is null or not?!

Hope this help.

Comment: In the logs before the null pointer I get the logger output [p-nio-80-exec-6] c.e.yaadle.uplift.user.UserDaoImpl       : I am inside findbyemail  [p-nio-80-exec-6] c.e.yaadle.uplift.user.UserDaoImpl       : Query made SELECT EMAIL,PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME='don@gmail,com' ERROR 9680 --- [p-nio-80-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

Comment: @DON: can you check your query:  Query made SELECT EMAIL,PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME='don@gmail,com'? is it "don@gmail,com"? COMMA or DOT?

Answer (score 0):

I was successful after defining the parameter as said with ?